# Category Sorting Product list: How to take off position from attributes?

Tags: category, sorting

Magento 1.9.0.1

In the admin panel, you have the ability to sort categories by attributes as seen here: http://inchoo.net/magento/changing-default-category-sort-order-in-magento/

Now I have sorted products in categories by:

- price (default)
- name
- position

I need to remove *position* from the menu leaving only *price* and *name*

I don't want to edit every single category view from catalago-->manage categories because I have too many categories in the store.

I need to act in configurations

Answer (score 2):

I've modified the toolbar template file:

```
/<your_theme>/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml
```

replacing this:

```
<ul>
  <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key => $_order): ?>
    ...
```

with this:

```
<ul>
  <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key => $_order): ?>
    <?php if ($_key === 'position') { continue; } ?>
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

add this to css

```
.sorter-options > option[value=position] {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did it this simple way, maybe somebody needs smthing like this

```
<div class="form-item-select">
        <select id="sorter" data-role="sorter" class="sorter-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableOrders() as $_key => $_order): ?>
                <option value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_key ?>"
                    <?php if ($block->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?>
                        selected="selected"
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    >
                    <?php if ($block->isOrderCurrent($_order === "Price")): ?>
                        Final Price
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sort by %1', $_order)) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -5):

follow the steps below.

1. Go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes
2. Select position from the attribute list
3. Under Properties > Frontend Properties, set the display to "No" for the following options;

   - Used in Product Listing
   - Used for Sorting in Product Listing

Remember to flush the cache if you had cache enabled.

Comment: There's no position attribute in the attribute list in my Magento 1.9.1. I have unsuccessful tried to search **position** and its translation in the site language, even **place**. Nothing